# How can I repeat strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how would I create a string of repeating strings x number of times:

```
var s = new String("&nbsp;",3);

//s would now be "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is no such function, but hey, you can create it:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(times) {
   return (new Array(times + 1)).join(this);
};
```

Usage:

```
var s = "&nbsp;".repeat(3);
```

Of course you could write this as part of a standalone group of functions:

```
var StringUtilities = {
    repeat: function(str, times) { 
       return (new Array(times + 1)).join(str);
    }
    //other related string functions...
};
```

Usage:

```
var s = StringUtilities.repeat("&nbsp;", 3);
```

Comment: I prefer that solution to mine. I didn't know we could append functionality to String class and possibly to any class.

Comment: Ahhh, go away with prototype extension...

Comment: @Sybiam -- you can, but don't.  Well, if it's something universally useful, OK, but something like this, put it in a library.

Comment: @Malvolio I updated my answer to accomodate your point of view as well...

Comment: @Ivo I personally love prototype extension; why not make use of a language construct that is available to you?

Comment: @filmaj Well Prototype.js is one example for why it's bad.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Array.join`:

```
function repeat(str, times) {
    return new Array(times + 1).join(str);
}

> repeat('&nbsp;', 3)
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a neat way that involves no loops.  In addition to being concise, I'm pretty sure using join is much more efficient for very large strings.

```
function repeat(str, num) { 
    return (new Array(num+1)).join(str); 
}
```

You could also put this code on the String prototype, but I'm of the mindset that it's a bad idea to mess with the prototype of built in types.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best and only way to achieve this is to loop over your string.. As far as I know, there is no such feature in any languages.

```
function multiString(text, count){
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        ret += text;
    }
    return ret;
}

var myString = multiString("&nbsp;", 3);
```

But I guess you could figure it out.

Comment: Perl has the X operator to repeat things like this - there are other languages as well

Comment: I know in python and from a solution bellow we can do it with arrays and join. But I don't consider these solutions as features. I don't know about the X operator but nowadays I'm not surprised about Perl. After I saw the Periodic table of operators for perl. Nothing will surprise me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried with a loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     s += "&nbsp;"; }
```

?