# Javascript: repeat a string in given a count parameter with a while loop

Tags: javascript, string, loops, recursion, while-loop

I did a very thorough search before asking this, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I want to preface that this is my fifth day coding in JavaScript, so be easy on me, please!

I'm taking a preparatory coding course for a full-fledged program and one of our objectives was to write a function `repeatString(string, count)` that takes a string and the number of times you want it repeated as parameters. Here is my version with recursion:

```
function repeatString(string, count) {
    if ( count === 0 ) {
        return "";
    }
    if ( count === 1 ) {
        return string;
    }
    if ( count > 1 ) {
    return string + repeatString(string, count - 1); 
    }
}
```

We were then supposed to rewrite the function using while instead of recursion. This is where I got stuck:

```
function repeatString(string, count) {

    var num = 0;

    if ( count === 0 ) {
        return "";
    }
    while ( num < count ) {
        num += 1;
        return string;
    }
}
```

My current code returns a string only once no matter the count, unless the count is zero. I'm sure there is a glaring error right in front of me but my beginner eyes are not catching it.

Comment: For future reference `return` will exit the function as soon as it is called, so your while loop will only make it through one iteration before breaking. This comes in very handy in a lot of situations but in this case you should so as @mikeb is suggesting.

Comment: @OhAuth That is incredibly useful to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you need to build the string before you return it.  If you're not using recursion, you only return once:

```
function repeatString(string, count) {

  var num = 0;
  var str = "";
  if ( count === 0 ) {
      return "";
  }
  while ( num < count ) {
      num += 1;
      str = str + string;
  }
  return str;
}
```

> > repeatString("asdf", 2)
> >
> > "asdfasdf"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you for the prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

here an easy one:

```
function repeatString(string, count) {
    return new Array(count + 1).join(string);
}

repeatString('asd', 2) // "asdasd"
```

Comment: I forgot about this one, nice.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I repeat strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549894/how-can-i-repeat-strings-in-javascript) provides two elegant solutions, both based on initializing an array of the needed size, then joining its items to form the resulting string.

If using while is a must, then you still can make make the function shorter.
Note, using reserved words to name your variables is poor style, so I replaced "string" with "s", and "str" with "result" for clarity.

```
function repeatString(s, count) {
  var result = "";
  var num = 1;
  while ( num++ <= count ) {
      result += s;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: *"We were then supposed to rewrite the function **using while** instead of recursion"*

Answer (score 0):

Here is one too, with es6

```
var repeater = (str) => {
       return (times) => {
            return [...Array(times)].reduce((p,c) => {
              return p.concat(str)
            }, []).join('')
       }

}

repeater('yoyo')(10)

or

  var R = repeater('test')
      R(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer:

```
function repeatString(str,num){
   return str.repeat(num);
}
repeatString('hello', 2);
```